# plpgsql - selecting array of multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create procedure which selects data, processes and returns them, but I am struggling how to define array variable for multiple columns.

This works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing_array_return()
RETURNS TABLE(id BIGINT) AS
$body$
DECLARE
    l_rows BIGINT[];
BEGIN
    -- select data using for update etc
        l_rows := ARRAY(
        SELECT 1 AS id
        UNION 
        SELECT 2 AS id
    );
    -- do some stuff
    -- return previously selected data
    RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT *
            FROM UNNEST(l_rows);
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

But I want to do this for 2 or more columns without using composite type or rowtype:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing_array_return()
RETURNS TABLE(id BIGINT, text VARCHAR2) AS
$body$
DECLARE
    l_rows -- what should I put here?
BEGIN
    -- select data using for update etc
        l_rows := ARRAY(
        SELECT 1 AS id, 'test' AS text
        UNION 
        SELECT 2 AS id, 'test2' AS text
    );
    -- do some stuff
    -- return previously selected data
    RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT *
            FROM UNNEST(l_rows);
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

In oracle I could define record type and then table type of it, but I can't find how to do this in postgres. Maybe using wrong keywords when searching...

edit: this is how I would do this in Oracle (without returning).

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_row IS RECORD(
     id   NUMBER
    ,text VARCHAR2(10));
  TYPE t_tbl IS TABLE OF t_row;
  l_rows t_tbl := t_tbl(); --how to do this in postgres?
BEGIN
  SELECT *
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO l_rows
    FROM (SELECT 1 AS id
                ,'test' AS text
            FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 2 AS id
                ,'test' AS text
            FROM dual);
END;
```

Anything similiar in postgres? Like record but for array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do the same in Postgres:

Create the record type:

```
create type footype as (id bigint, text_ varchar);
```

Then use an array of that type in your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing_array_return()
RETURNS TABLE(id BIGINT, text VARCHAR) AS
$body$
DECLARE
    l_rows footype[];
BEGIN
    -- select data using for update etc
        l_rows := ARRAY(
        SELECT (1, 'test')
        UNION 
        SELECT (2, 'test2')
    );
    -- do some stuff
    -- return previously selected data
    RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT *
            FROM UNNEST(l_rows);
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/UMRZFO54266

The expression `(1, 'test')` creates a single value of record type. As that is assigned to a typed variable, there is no need to alias the columns (and in fact you can't do that anyway).

Unrelated, but: the language name is an identifier. Do not put that in single quotes.

---

<sup>Note that `text` is also a keyword in Postgres because it's a data type. You shouldn't use it as a column name</sup>

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I was looking to do this without creating types in DB. It is possible do define types directly in procedure, so You don't need to create them in DB.

Comment: @kaaja: well you said "*In oracle I could define record type and then table type of it*" - the above is the equivalent to that. Where do the rows actually come from? Maybe you could use that table's type for the array?

Comment: I added Oracle sample to make it clearer. I would like to avoid creating DB composite types which will be used only in that function. Table rowtype also isn't an option as I would like to calculate additional columns in that select.

Comment: The only (ugly) other option you have is to declare one array for each column.

Comment: @kaaja: or - if you can live with losing some type safety - you could store the data in a JSONB array.